# Error while trying to check the correct format of email with a reactive form in Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-forms

I am trying to create with Ionic2 a login (reactive) form with 2 fields: email and password.

I want the form to have some checks, specifically:

- both fields are required
- email must have a correct email format

Here is the code

**login.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormGroup, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import {Session} from '../../providers/session';
import {User} from '../../model/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  form:FormGroup;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private session: Session
  ) {
      this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
                    email: ['', [
                            Validators.required,
                            Validators.pattern('^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$')
                            ]],
                    password: ['', Validators.required]
                  })
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }

  onSubmit(formData) {
    // check login
  }

}
```

**login.html**

```
    <ion-header>
     <ion-navbar>
       <button ion-button menuToggle>
         <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
       </button>
       <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
     </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content padding="true">


      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
          <ion-item>
              <ion-input type="email" placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" name="email" required></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
              <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" name="password" required></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <button ion-button color="primary" block>Log in</button>
      </form>

    </ion-content>
```

The problem is that the check on email format does not work correctly: the  'email' FormControl has status always invalid, even if the email typed is correct.

Any help to understand what I am doing wrong is very much appreciated

Comment: did you input data in invalid format?

Comment: I'm like 99% sure it's your regex that is not working. I've been fighting it with myself in a similar case. And BTW, I tried your regex, but it didn't work in my app. The closest I have gotten to a working regex is: `Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$')` Seems to work fine... BUT after `@` it takes 3 letters and then it says the e-mail is valid. BUT if you put a dot, then it demands that at least 2 characters is needed after that. So I throw this regex at you, and PLEASE share if you get it working fully, I would REALLY appreciate it :)

Comment: This regex is working. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while setting up my signup page. Not all `regex` patterns where working inside `Validators.pattern`. I had to use a custom validator. Here is how you can set this up (considering regex is accurate).

```
 import { FormControl , FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
 export class CustomValidator {
   static emailValidator(email: FormControl){
     let EMAIL_REGEXP = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
     return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(email.value) ? null : {
       invalidEmail: true
     }
   }
 }
```

Then in `component`

```
  email: ['', CustomValidator.emailValidator],
```